# Cannot load css files into osgi bundle

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx, osgi, javafx-8

I want to create JavaFX application based on several osgi bundles. I use Felix framework for osgi container. I face the same issue as this post

[Exception logged when using custom css in JavaFX in Felix OSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187147/exception-logged-when-using-custom-css-in-javafx-in-felix-osgi)

How I can set globally

```
-Dbinary.css=false
```

Into the start JavaFX method. I would like at a low level to configure this.

Answer (score 2):

The solution: 
I converted the css files into bss and placed them together with the css files:

```
javafxpackager -createbss -srcfiles love.css -outdir . -outfile love
```

[How to convert css into bss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068627/how-to-convert-css-into-bss)

It's a quick fix for now I hope that it will be fixed into next JavaFX versions. I use Java 8b115

I hope it will be useful for someone.