# java.io.IOException: rsrc:application/application.bss wrong binary CSS version: 5. Expected version less than or equal to3

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, fxmlloader

I have a created a sample application using javafx. Due to certain restrictions in my network, I cannot install fxpackaging tools such at e(fx)clipse etc.

I have created jar using eclipse(version 4.5.1)
application works perfectly when I execute jar file using below command in cmd

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

#### Problem 1 :(resolved)

I have observed this exception in 'command prompt'

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Coult not open InputStream for URL 
'rsrc:application/application.bss'
```

I have created bss files using below command(executed at project root level)

```
javafxpackager -createbss -srcfiles application.css -outdir .
```

Then copied the output bss file to proper location(program excepts resource located a specific folder).

#### Problem 2: (not resolved)

Initial exception has been resolved & I could see the fonts are displayed as expected. But in the background I could see below exception

> java.io.IOException: rsrc:application/application.bss wrong binary CSS
>   version: 5. Expected version less than or equal to3

### Question:

How to fix this 'wrong binary CSS version' exception(displayed in command prompt)? 
Please note, I don't see any issues with application,which is running in foreground.

For testing purpose I have used a one liner styling code in my application.css file

```
.label{-fx-text-fill: black;}
```

→ jar file created using eclipse (JDK 1.7) & windows is running on JRE 1.7.0_91

**css file** : one liner as mentioned above

[image: css file]

**bss file**
[image: bss file]

**package structure**

[image: package]

Comment: Could you post your JDK versions: the one used to create the project, and the bss file, and the one you are running your project with (`java -version`)?

Comment: @JoséPereda, Jar file created using eclipse (having jdk 1.7) and application.bss created using windows JRE version 1.7.0_91

Comment: Can we see the bss file that is causing this exception?

Comment: @Abob78, I have attached images to my question. For testing purpose, I have put only a label in my *.css file.

Comment: Do you have a JDK8 installed? Make sure you are not using it.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, so it must be how the css file was compiled that's causing the problem. You said you couldn't install anything, but could you update eclipse with the javafx packages by adding a repo (requires no admin priveledges)?

Comment: @JoséPereda, I have installed JDK1.8 in my desktop, but I have selected jdk1.7 in eclipse, I have configured my windows PATH variable to JRE 1.7

Comment: @Abob78,  our corporate network restricts direct internet access. I cannot add any plugins beyond the software provided to us.

Comment: @Raju okay, that's fine. To clarify, is every related file class and css file in the jar? Are both `application.bss` and `application.class` in the same place inside your jar? Or are you using fxml for everything? Basically, whats does the inside of your jar look like?

Comment: @Abob78, My jar has all the necessary files

Comment: @Abob78,@JoséPereda I have posted my observation in the answer. This is not full solution, because the utility is supposed to run in JRE 1.7 & above. Can you check, if you can help me with this observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As José Pereda stated, bss is version 5 on Java 8. Based on the [JavaFX 8 CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label) for label, the syntax is correct. However, this is for Java 8, while you are currently using Java 7. If you have Java 8, configure eclipse and set the build path to use it and set your `PATH` variable accordingly to Java 8.

### If the problem persists:

If it's not working even after the update, we'll try to compile it slightly differently to see what happens. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068627/how-to-convert-css-into-bss), you don't need the `.css` file once you have compiled the `.bss` file.

Create a `Test` folder somewhere easily accessible. We'll be using this to see how the files being compiled separately will effect the exception since updating Java has done nothing at this point.

First, try to run the program with the essential files. If your `Main.java` file doesn't rely on the other java files in your project, then copy that file in to the `test` folder we recently created. If not, copy only the necessary parts that use the `css` (such as the scene and label that calls the `css file`), and paste that into a new `Main.java` in the new `test` folder.

Continuing forward you're going to have to open a command window in your test folder. You can do this by pressing SHIFT + RIGHT CLICK in the `test` folder on Windows Explorer and click `Open command window here`

After this, compile `Main.java` by typing this in the newly opened commnd prompt window:

```
javac Main.java
```

Next, copy `appication.css` but rename it to `Main.css`, for testing purposes. Then, run this in the command prompt window (You didn't have the `-outfile` arguement; this shouldn't matter, but it's a slight safety measure):

```
javafxpackager -createbss -srcfiles Main.css -outdir . -outfile Main
```

Now you should see that you have `Main.css`. Now, with the same command window you can easily run the file and see what happens.

```
java Main
```

Please leave a comment if this help you and which part of this answer you actually used to fix the problem if this answer did help you, thanks!

Comment: I would like to fix my issue before finishing the formalities of this question ;) I have installed JDK 1.7.0_76, unfortunately it is not generating any bss file. It is not even showing any error. I will try with JDK 1.7.0_79 & let you know my finding.

Comment: test with jdk 1.7.0_95 , javafxpackager is not throwing any error & not creating any files at all :(

Comment: packager is not working it seems. [screenshot reference](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WCOr0.png)

Comment: Looks like there is a bug with javafxpackager, but the rootcause was found, hence I am awarding bounty. Thanks @Abob78

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from José Pereda, Abob78 I did an experiment. I have figured it out that, the issue is not observed if I am using JRE 1.8

1. **Command prompt 1 :** pointed JRE 1.7.0_91 → above exception observed
2. **Command prompt 2 :** pointed JRE 1.8.0_40 → **exception** not observed.

Both running at same time & using same JAR file.

Comment: Bss level 5 is from JDK8, so that's why you don't get the issue running JDK8. The question remains: where do you run the javafxpackager from?

Comment: @JoséPereda, that's a good catch. I think, that's the root cause of the issue. Though JRE is pointing to 1.7 directory, when I run `where javafxpackager.exe` it is pointing to JDK 1.8 directory.

Comment: Make sure you run it from the JDK7 distribution, and check again, if it works I'll write a proper answer

Comment: @JoséPereda, I have these java versions available in my system jdk1.6.0_31,jdk1.6.0_39,jdk1.7.0_25,jdk1.8.0_40,jdk1.8.0_51,jre7. Unfortunately, javafxpackager.exe is available in jdk1.8(2 directories) only. This utility should work in JRE1.7 and above. Is this possible ?

Comment: JDK 1.7.0_65 to the latest 1.7.0_79 all have javafxpackager. You may need to upgrade your JDK7 version.

Comment: @Raju Glad to hear that it seems to be just the version of java! As a side note, 1.8.0_74 is the latest version of Java at the time of this comment. I suggest updating, but if you can't at least delete JDK 1.7 off the computer so it doesn't interfere. It will also allow you to see what needs to be re-configured, since it will give you errors if you missed something.

Comment: @Abob78, This utility is supposed to work in multiple java versions. So, I am maintaining all the versions to test the utility in all the java versions.

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javafxpackager.html), `javafxpackager` is only avaliable on java 8 and could possibly be named `javapackager`. Below Java 8, you would have to use [native bundles](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx)